# Does Liquibase Rollback automatically when Update command fails?

Tags: database, liquibase

Suppose I have a changeLog file that contains 3 changeSets. If I run the Liquibase Update command from the command line and it fails on the second changeSet, will Liquibase RollBack to before the update command began execution? Or will it keep the changes from changeSet 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changeset 1 will still be applied to the database and the DATABASECHANGELOG table will reflect that the changeset was applied. If you then fix whatever problem caused the update to fail and re-run your update, it will see that changeset 1 has already been deployed and only deploy changesets 2 and 3.